# makefile undefined reference error

Tags: makefile

I'm having trouble compiling my project I am coding files wordbench2.h, wordbench2.cpp, makefile.wb2, oaa_bst.h for the main file I was given (main_wb2.cpp) I was wondering if anyone sees something wrong in my makefile

```
LIB     = /home/courses/cop4530p/LIB
CPP     = $(LIB)/cpp
TCPP    = $(LIB)/tcpp
PROJ    = .
INCPATH = -I$(PROJ)-I$(CPP)-I$(TCPP)
CC      = g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -I. -I$(CPP)

#target:
all: wb2.x foaa.x moaa.x
#foaa+.x

main_wb2.o: wordbench2.h main_wb2.cpp
        $(CC) -c main_wb2.cpp

foaa.o: wordbench2.h foaa.cpp
        $(CC) -c foaa.cpp

moaa.o: wordbench2.h moaa.cpp
        $(CC) -c moaa.cpp

wordbench2.o: wordbench2.h wordbench2.cpp wordify.cpp
        $(CC) -c wordbench2.cpp

xstring.o: $(CPP)/xstring.h $(CPP)/xstring.cpp
        $(CC) $(INCPATH) -c $(CPP)/xstring.cpp

wb2.x: main_wb2.o wordbench2.o xstring.o
        $(CC) -o wb2.x main_wb2.o

foaa.x: foaa.o wordbench2.o xstring.o
        $(CC) -o foaa.x foaa.o

moaa.x: moaa.o wordbench2.o xstring.o
        $(CC) -o moaa.x moaa.o
```

Error

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -I. -I/home/courses/cop4530p/LIB/cpp -o wb2.x main_wb2.o                   
main_wb2.o: In function `main':
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `WordBench::WordBench()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `fsu::String::String()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `fsu::String::String()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `fsu::operator>>(std::istream&, fsu::String&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `fsu::operator>>(std::istream&, fsu::String&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x235): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `WordBench::ReadText(fsu::String const&, bool)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `fsu::operator>>(std::istream&, fsu::String&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x2d3): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x300): undefined reference to `fsu::operator>>(std::istream&, fsu::String&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x317): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x33f): undefined reference to `WordBench::ReadText(fsu::String const&, bool)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x371): undefined reference to `fsu::operator>>(std::istream&, fsu::String&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x3b5): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x3e2): undefined reference to `fsu::operator>>(std::istream&, fsu::String&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x3f9): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x42f): undefined reference to `WordBench::WriteReport(fsu::String const&, unsigned short, unsigned short, std::_Ios_Fmtflags, std::_Ios_Fmtflags) const'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x44d): undefined reference to `fsu::String::operator=(fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `fsu::String::Size() const'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x488): undefined reference to `fsu::String::Cstr() const'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x4d9): undefined reference to `fsu::operator<<(std::ostream&, fsu::String const&)'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x572): undefined reference to `WordBench::ClearData()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x595): undefined reference to `WordBench::ShowSummary() const'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x67a): undefined reference to `fsu::String::~String()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x686): undefined reference to `fsu::String::~String()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x695): undefined reference to `WordBench::~WordBench()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x6cb): undefined reference to `fsu::String::~String()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x6dc): undefined reference to `fsu::String::~String()'
main_wb2.cpp:(.text+0x6f0): undefined reference to `WordBench::~WordBench()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [wb2.x] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In this rule:

```
wb2.x: main_wb2.o wordbench2.o xstring.o
        $(CC) -o wb2.x main_wb2.o
```

you list `wordbench2.o` and `xstring.o` in your prerequisites list, but you didn't put them onto the compile line.

Why are you rewriting the same things over and over?  That just leads to silly errors like this.  Use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) to avoid retyping and getting things wrong:

```
wb2.x: main_wb2.o wordbench2.o xstring.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Ditto for your other linker rules.

Comment: And for your compile rules put the `*.cpp` as first prerequisite and use automatic variable `$<` (first prerequisite) in your recipe.